# What are the advantages/disadvantages of perforce “jobs” over an external bug tracking system?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to understand what perforce “jobs” provide over an external bug tracking system and just putting the bug ID in the check-in comment.

I was hoping that "job" could help with [How do I see if a branch contains a bug fix in Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024381/how-do-i-see-if-a-branch-contains-a-bug-fix-in-perforce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [bugtracker](http://kb.perforce.com/?article=52), Perforce jobs are somewhat basic. They can be created and modified with the [P4V GUI client](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_visual_client) or using [`p4 job`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/job.html) and [`p4 jobs`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/jobs.html) on the command line.

The idea is for them to serve as a link (a *connector* as Perforce calls it or an *interface* as a developer might look at it) to a third party issue management system and basically provide the information which changelists were committed for which issue. The issue management system can then tap into this information using the [Perforce Defect Tracking Gateway](http://maillist.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4dtg.html) (PDF documentation [here](http://maillist.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4dtg/p4dtg.pdf)) and generate bugfix charts or statistics for management or whatever.

We are using this with [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) in both directions with some success. The basics worked pretty much straight out of the box, more advanced use cases (such as e.g. which bugs were fixes in which release ?) or integration with other bugtrackers may require [modification of the Perforce job model](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/05_jobspec.html).

One of the advantages over tracking changelist and issue numbers using commit comments is that you can select the job/issue from a dropdown box when you commit a changelist using P4V.

In practice, developers tend to forget to add the job information when they commit a changelist. This can be enforced using [Perforce triggers](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/06_scripting.html#1045367).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing.  Take it from someone who endured years of aggravation working with the Perforce/[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) integration mechanisms (the latest being the Perforce Defect Tracking Gateway which uses Perforce jobs as part of the integration).  They provide very little return on a significant investment in time setting them up and then trying to figure what went wrong when they stop working (which is often).

I now do just what you suggest.  I simply put the FogBugz case number in the Perforce check-in comment, then add that Perforce changelist number to the FogBugz case upon resolving it.  As simple *and* reliable as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

We put the issue ID in the comment but also have a Perforce trigger that updates the issue database (JIRA) with the changelist number. During the next build the automated build process also updates the issue with the actual build number.

A very nice part of this implantation is that the trigger gives an error if the issue is not marked as in progress or the developer doing the check-in is not working on the issue.  Therefore it is uncommon for a miss-typed issues ID number to get past the checks.